# JSF - conditionally show one of two dialogs

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have two Primefaces `p:dialogs` in my page and I have two buttons to display them (the one is a delete button, the other one is an edit button).

I set the visible attribute of the dialogs as follows: `visible="#{fn:length(bean.selectedItems) gt 0}` for the delete button and `visible="#{fn:length(bean.selectedItems) eq 1}`, so I can delete multiple elements, but only edit one at the same time.

Now the bean is ViewScoped, so if there is exactly one item selected, and there is a commandButton without ajax submit pressed, both of the dialogs are displayed, which obviously is not what I want.

What is the easiest way to show the appropriate dialog only when needed?

I don't want to set an extra bean attribute for that, so let's consider that a trivial solution. Is there another way? Maybe setting the name of the action to a view scoped parameter? Or using the rendered attributes and managing the show/hide from javascript callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way is

```html
<p:commandButton value="DELETE" 
                 onclick="deleteDialog.show()" 
                 disabled="#{fn:length(bean.selectedItems) eq 0}" />

<p:commandButton value="EDIT" 
                 onclick="editDialog.show()" 
                 disabled="#{fn:length(bean.selectedItems) ne 1}" />
```

Comment: I ended up implementing very similar to this.